# Controller path in ASP.NET MVC application is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application with a navigation menu in it. The structure of that menu is defined in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
  <item Text="Download" NavigateUrl="Home/Download" />
  <item Text="Delete" NavigateUrl="Home/Delete"  />
  <item Text="Rename" NavigateUrl="Home/Rename"  />
  <item Text="Upload" NavigateUrl="Home/Upload"  />
</items>


  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // DXCOMMENT: Pass a data model for GridView

            return View(NorthwindDataProvider.GetCustomers());    
        }

        public ActionResult GridViewPartialView() 
        {
            // DXCOMMENT: Pass a data model for GridView in the PartialView method's second parameter
            return PartialView("GridViewPartialView", NorthwindDataProvider.GetCustomers());
        }

        public ActionResult Download()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Rename()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Delete()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

The problem I have with this is when I navigate to e.g. to "Home/Delete" and then to "Home/Rename" the page is not found because the searched path is "Home/Home/Rename". But if i remove the home form the path it's also not working because then for the inital click on "/Delete" the page is not found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look into Areas.  Also, we'd need to see your routing, not just this menu definition.

Comment: You need relative paths. Use `@Url.Action("Download", "Home")` to ensure you urls are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your URLs with a slash, otherwise it will be relative to the current folder.

```
<items>
  <item Text="Download" NavigateUrl="/Home/Download" />
  <item Text="Delete" NavigateUrl="/Home/Delete"  />
  <item Text="Rename" NavigateUrl="/Home/Rename"  />
  <item Text="Upload" NavigateUrl="/Home/Upload"  />
</items>
```